# Receiving bytes on server in C from Android

Tags: android, c, sockets, server, serversocket

I have successfully connected my android phone as client to a raspberry pi as server.

The next step is sending data to the raspberry pi using bytes. Am I doing it correctly for the Android in Java?

```
socket.getOutputStream().write(String.valueOf(progress).getBytes());
```

Thereafter, on my raspberry pi side, I will have to receive the bytes in C. I am facing problems in receiving data on server. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  int welcomeSocket,clientSocket;
  char buffer[1024];
  struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
  struct sockaddr_storage serverStorage;
  socklen_t addr_size;
  ssize_t nread;

  /*---- Create the socket. The three arguments are: ----*/
  /* 1) Internet domain 2) Stream socket 3) Default protocol (TCP in this case) */
  welcomeSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  /*---- Configure settings of the server address struct ----*/
  /* Address family = Internet */
  serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order */
  serverAddr.sin_port = htons(9999);
  /* Set IP address to localhost */
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*---- Bind the address struct to the socket ----*/
  bind(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));

  /*---- Listen on the socket, with 5 max connection requests queued ----*/
  if(listen(welcomeSocket,5)==0){
    printf("Listening\n");
}
  else
    printf("Error\n");

  /*---- Accept call creates a new socket for the incoming connection ----*/
  addr_size = sizeof serverStorage;
  clientSocket = accept(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
  printf("Successfully Connected!!!\n\r");

  //Receive data from android  
  //recv(welcomeSocket,buffer,1024,0);
  nread = recvfrom(clientSocket, buffer,1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
  if(nread==-1)
  perror("Error!");
  else
  printf("Data received: %s",buffer);


return 0;

}
```

As from Pravin's comment, I tried using the Recvfrom and perror, it showed an error of -1.

Comment: Yes, you can use recv() to receive bytes. What is return values of recv? Is it '0' or '-1'? You can use perror() or errno to display error message.

Comment: sorry, how do i show the return value of recv? just do a return recv(socket,buffer,BUFSIZ,0); ?

Comment: To get return value you can hold in variable retVal=recv(). Refer [man recv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) and for example of recv/recvfrom refer example in [link](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo).

Comment: Ah i see, alright thanks I will try it tomorrow and let you know the results!

Comment: Thanks Pravin! I solved the problem. And also may i ask, how do i set up a Listening for Receiving, so if only when I press send on the android, then the receive on my pi will run? I should do a While(1) loop?

Answer (score 0):

Okay! I realised the problem. I realised I didnt use the client socket created previously. I kept on using the Server's socket lol. Didn't notice it at first. I used an example to see what was different between my server and the example server, which really helped!

http://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/